# How to make a query on multiple columns without writting all possible permutations?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm at my first question on stackexchange, as i have a few days since I struggle on this matter:

I want to make a complex query(PLSQL) on a table that has **col1,col2,col3,col4,col5** having values like (names: which are split- one part per column)

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|  ID  | Col1   |  Col2  |  Col3  | Col4 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| (#1) | Andrew | Joan   | Bach   | Mike |
| (#2) | Mark   | Andrew | Livy   |      |
| (#3) | Joan   | Arch   | Donnie |      |
| (#4) | Joan   | Andrew | Lyx    |      |
+------+--------+--------+--------+------+
```

Number of name parts differ from 1 to 5.

I want to search in different combinations like this:

- search for *Bach Joan Mike* - get **#1, #3,#4** - in this order
- search for *Andrew Bach* - get the following order **#1,#2,#4** - in this order

I don't like the idea of using a looooong query in which I will write all possible permutations in order to mach each part of my search string

What I'd like to achieve is this:

- **first set**: match all those n parts (both **Bach** and **Joan** and **Bach** match, in any order)
- **second set**: match n-1 parts (at least **N-1** of my search parts match the row, in any order)
- **third set**: match **n-2** parts

I use a ORACLE database and I was thinking on making it in a stored procedure: match_my_set(query_str,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5). I would write at least 5 loops (loop into loop) in order to achieve this, but I doubt it is a professional idea . .

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your question isnt clear... what mean `get #1, #3,#4 order`   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Well, I added a small update. Hope it helps

Comment: I make an update with why I thing you have? Please check or reverse if isnt correct. You mention col5 but your example looks like only have 4

Comment: Well your question still not clear, but looks like you need https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on 11g or higher, you can unpivot your columns into rows; this is using a CTE to provide your sample data:

```
with t (id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) as (
  select 1, 'Andrew', 'Joan', 'Bach', 'Mike', null from dual
  union all select 2, 'Mark', 'Andrew', 'Livy', null, null from dual
  union all select 3, 'Joan', 'Arch', 'Donnie', null, null from dual
  union all select 4, 'Joan', 'Andrew', 'Lyx' , null, null from dual
)
select * from t
unpivot (name for col_no in (col1 as 1, col2 as 2, col3 as 3, col4 as 4, col5 as 5));

        ID     COL_NO NAME 
---------- ---------- ------
         1          1 Andrew
         1          2 Joan  
         1          3 Bach  
         1          4 Mike  
         2          1 Mark  
         2          2 Andrew
         2          3 Livy  
...
```

Then you can look for matches against the single name column:

```
select distinct id
from (
  select * from t
  unpivot (name for col_no in (col1 as 1, col2 as 2, col3 as 3, col4 as 4, col5 as 5))
)
where name in ('Bach', 'Joan', 'Mike')
order by id;

        ID
----------
         1
         3
         4
```

I *think* you want to make the ordering more complicated though, by counting how many of the terms match in each row. If so you can do:

```
select id, count(*) as cnt
from (
  select * from t
  unpivot (name for col_no in (col1 as 1, col2 as 2, col3 as 3, col4 as 4, col5 as 5))
)
where name in ('Bach', 'Joan', 'Mike')
group by id;

        ID        CNT
---------- ----------
         1          3
         4          1
         3          1
```

and then have another level of inline view to order by the count, with some way to break ties:

```
select id
from (
  select id, count(*) as cnt
  from (
    select * from t
    unpivot (name for col_no in (col1 as 1, col2 as 2, col3 as 3, col4 as 4, col5 as 5))
  )
  where name in ('Bach', 'Joan', 'Mike')
  group by id
)
order by cnt desc, id;
```

Which gets the same result with your sample data. Changing the `IN` condition to user `('Andrew', 'Bach')` also gets 1,2,4 with both versions.

Depending on how you're getting the values you're searching for, you might want to use an array instead (via a table collection expression and a join), or tokenise a string containing all the search words, or some other variation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using Oracle's collections (which should work in 10g or later)

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME( ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Andrew', 'Joan',   'Bach',   'Mike' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Mark',   'Andrew', 'Livy',   NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Joan',   'Arch',   'Donnie', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Joan',   'Andrew', 'Lyx',    NULL FROM DUAL;

CREATE TYPE stringlist AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         stringlist( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
           MULTISET INTERSECT
           stringlist( 'Bach', 'Joan', 'Mike' ) -- Search terms
           AS names
  FROM   TABLE_NAME t
)
WHERE  names IS NOT EMPTY
ORDER BY CARDINALITY( names ) DESC, ID;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID COL1   COL2   COL3   COL4
---------- ------ ------ ------ ----
         1 Andrew Joan   Bach   Mike 
         3 Joan   Arch   Donnie      
         4 Joan   Andrew Lyx
```

Answer (score -1):

This is untested, but I think it'll work.  First, you need a function that will split a search string by spaces into a table:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[SplitSpace] (@StringList varchar(4000))

RETURNS @Result Table(Value varchar(50))

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @x XML
    SELECT @X = CAST('<A>' + REPLACE(@StringList, ' ', '</A><A>') + '</A>' AS XML)

    INSERT INTO @Result
    SELECT t.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as inVal
    FROM @X.nodes('/A') AS x(t)

    RETURN
END
```

This function will come in handy elsewhere, too, and you can easily modify it to split by commas or any other value, if needed.

Next, you need to create a query that returns the desired results (when you're done testing, you can convert this to a stored procedure and accept the search string as a parameter):

```
DECLARE @SearchString varchar(255) = 'Bach Joan Mike'
DECLARE @SearchTable TABLE(Value varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @SearchTable 
SELECT DISTINCT Value 
FROM SplitSpace(@SearchString)

SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM MyTable M
JOIN @SearchTable S
    ON S.Value = Col1
    OR S.Value = Col2
    OR S.Value = Col3
    OR S.Value = Col4
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Number of Hits]
        FROM @SearchTable
        WHERE Value = M.Col1
        OR Value = M.Col2
        OR Value = M.Col3
        OR Value = M.Col4
    ) t
ORDER BY t.[Number of Hits] DESC
```

Basically, you're saying "give me all the records where one or more of the "name" columns exists in the search string.

Then, you're saying, with the Cross Apply, "for each row, tell me how many hits I have".  Then, all you have to do is order by the number of hits and you're all set.

Note: it's possible that someone could enter "Andrew Andrew Bach" as a search string.  If they did so, you would get 2 hits for each column that has Andrew in it and only one for each one that had Bach.  That is why you select distinct value from the function-returned table; it eliminates those duplicates.  Also, if you have multiple matches, you would get that record returned twice, since it's an inner join, so you select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4 from those results, to eliminate those duplicates, as well.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That looks like it's a SQL Server solution; the OP is on an Oracle database.